# Can't seem to discover how to add collisions to Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

All the tutorials I've been able to find do not apply to me. If anyone could help, that'd be great. My main goal is to make a game sorta like Pacman, but I can't get collisions down. I'm kinda new to pygame and python. At the moment I just want the yellow circle to not go through the blue rectangle. If you know how to do this, please tell me! Again, I'm kinda a noob and I couldn't find any examples on this that worked. Thanks in advance!

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pyman by Jonathan Curtis")

x = 50
y = 50
radius = 10
speed = 5
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

def mazeWall(startx, starty, endx, endy):
    pygame.draw.line(win, BLUE, (startx, starty), (endx, endy), 10)

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_x]:
        print(x)
    if keys[pygame.K_y]:
        print(y)

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d] and not rightCollide:
        x += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += speed
   #Makes it impossible to go off the screen.
    if x > 480:
        x = 480
    if x < 20:
        x = 20
    if y > 480:
        y = 480
    if y < 20:
        y = 20

    #Draws character
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.circle(win, YELLOW, (x, y), radius)
    #Draws the maze border
    mazeWall(0, 1, 500, 1)
    mazeWall(0, 1, 0, 500)
    mazeWall(0, 499, 500, 499)
    mazeWall(500, 0, 500, 500)
    #Draws the rectangle
    mazeWall(100, 50, 200, 50)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your maze walls into a data structure / class.  Or even just keep them as a list of [pygame.Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)s.  Also maintain a Rect around your player-object.

For example:

```
maze_walls = [ pygame.Rect(0, 1, 500, 1), 
               pygame.Rect(0, 1, 0, 500),
               pygame.Rect(0, 499, 500, 499),
               pygame.Rect(500, 0, 500, 500),
               pygame.Rect(100, 50, 200, 50) ]

# this needs to have it's position updated when x & y change.
player_rect = pygame.Rect( x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius )
```

This will allow the code to use the built-in function [pygame.Rect.colliderect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) and/or [pygame.rect.collidelist()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) to check for collisions.

So this gives a drawing loop for the walls of:

```
#Draws character
win.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.draw.circle(win, YELLOW, (x, y), radius)
#Draws walls
for wall in maze_walls:
    pygame.draw.rect( win, BLUE, wall )
pygame.display.update()
```

So to check for collisions between your player and the walls, looping through the walls checking each one is fairly trivial:

```
# Did the player hit a wall
player_rect.center = (x, y)
for wall in maze_walls:
    if ( player_rect.colliderect( wall ) ):
        print( "Player hits wall: "+str( wall ) ) 
        # TODO: stop movement, whatever
```

Of course there's better ways to do this with [PyGame Sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), but I tried to keep the answer closest to what your code does now, while keeping it simple as possible.